# Create multiple email-server names

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record, hostname

My email server has two domains and the email hostname for each of them is mail.domain1.com.

I'm attempting to remove the 'mail' in mail.domain1.com for domain 1 and set domain 2 to domain2.com.

So that the detailed email headers for email sent from domain 1 only mentions domain 1, and email sent from domain 2 only mentions domain 2. i.e.

Email sent from domain 1 will read:

```
Received: from domain1.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.1])
```

And email sent from domain 2 will read:

```
Received: from domain2.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.1])
```

Instead of:

```
Received: from mail.domain1.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.1])
```

How would this be done?

Comment: You are asking for troubles...

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done, because that line is added by the server that you sent the message to, and the name it uses is determined by the rDNS you setup.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in various ways. You can add fake headers to the message that indicate relaying instead of submission. Or even you can setup some kind of virtualization for hosts `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` so relaying will occur IRL.